# JRequest::getCmd deprecate

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I dont find in the documentation How to modified this in joomla 2.5 if  `JRequest::getCmd` deprecate!!

```
function propios(){
    $model = &$this->getModel(JRequest::getCmd('view'));
    $view  = &$this->getView(JRequest::getCmd('view'), 'html');
    $view->setModel($model, true);
    $view->hardwarePropio();
}
```

any idea!

finally my control is

```
class HardwareController extends JController
{
    // busca los hardwares propios
    function propios(){
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $view = $jinput->getCmd('view', 'hardwares');
        JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);
        $model = &$this->getModel($view);
        $view = &$this->getView($view, 'html');
        $view->setModel($model, true);
        $view->$view->hardwarePropio();
    }

$view       = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'hardwares');
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);
```

If I erase the last two line, the link in the view to call a function dont work

```
<a href="<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php/hardware/propios">Equipos propios</a>
```

How to call the `function hardwarePropio()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this-

```
$model = &$this->getModel(JRequest::getCmd('view'));
$view  = &$this->getView(JRequest::getCmd('view'), 'html');
$view->setModel($model, true);
$view->hardwarePropio();
```

You can use this-

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view     = $jinput->getCmd('view', 'hardwares');

$model = &$this->getModel($view);
$view  = &$this->getView($view,'html');
$view->setModel($model, true);
$view->hardwarePropio();
```

API - http://doc.joomladev.eu/api25/Joomla-Platform/Application/JInput.html

Comment: Hi @Irfan thanks, can you show me How do it. I try this   $view = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'hardwares');
        JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);

        $model= JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('model', 'hardwares');

        $view->setModel($model, true);
        $view->hardwarePropio(); But I can't call the function hardawarePropio()

Comment: @Irfan I don't think you've defined `$app` on the second line here. Presumably you can replace `$app->input` with simply `$jinput` from the 1st line

Comment: @user852610:Could you also give code of modal and view.what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Irfan Thanks u so much, I try to call the function hardwarePropio and don´t call it.  In my hardwares/tmpl/default.php I have this line <a href="<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php/hardware/propios">Equipos propios: S-Ether</a> I put a echo but the code dont execute this function. any idea why?

Comment: @user852610:Check non sef link that what paramerters you are passing and what class and path structure you have.Naming convention is what I can say is the problem.